# os.mkdirall and change ownership to user with os.chown but how to get uid, gid of user

Tags: go

I need to mkdir on linux as root, so I run may app elevated with `sudo`.  But the app making use of this directory runs as a different user, `postgres`, so it errors out with a permission denied error message.

```
dir: = "/srv/tablepspaces/psql96/client"
err := os.MkdirAll(dir, os.FileMode(0775))
```

(for some reason the above results in 755 when i `stat` the dir on linux)

so I would like to chown the dir:

I need to use `os.Chown(name string, uid, gid int) error`

How do I get the uid and gid of a user without shelling out and getting the return and parsing of `id`

Answer (score 1):

```
err := os.MkdirAll(dir, os.FileMode(0775))
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("error creating tabelspace folders: %v ", err.Error())
}
if runtime.GOOS != "windows" {
    group, err := user.Lookup("postgres")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error looking up postgres user user info")
    }
    uid, _ := strconv.Atoi(group.Uid)
    gid, _ := strconv.Atoi(group.Gid)

    err = syscall.Chown(dir, uid, gid)
}
```